# Windows form application database: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm really a newbie at programming so do excuse me if my knowledge seems really inadequate. I'm doing a C# project for my school and I'm having problems starting my database up.

Here are some codes:

```
private void buttonPurchase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Purchase?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes) 
    {
        // store invoice
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =
             new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("CarDBConnectionString");
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into invoiceTbl(invoiceId, date, time) values (1, 21/6/2014, 11:13PM)";

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection1.Close();
     }
}
```

With these codes, I kept facing the error

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to to specification starting at index 0 1", under "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Also here are the codes from my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CarDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;InitialCatalogue=CarDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CarDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Draft_1.Properties.Settings.CarDBConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CarDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

I have tried googling everywhere but I can't seem to understand any of the solutions :-( Any help will be very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: @Steve the initial catalogue was auto generated, and changing it to catalog still gives me the same error :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A part from the typo in `"InitialCatalogue"` (the correct key is `Initial Catalog`), there is an error in your code.

You need to read the value of the connection string and pass it to the constructor of `SqlConnection`. The constructor expects a valid connection string not the key to your config file section

You could use

```
  string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                                        ["CarDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
  SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Comment: Yup I managed to get rid of the error! Thanks Steve for your help and prompt reply! :) Good day!

Answer (score 2):

@Steve made a good point: you have to pass a valid connection string.

Secondly, try to enclose parameters' values in single-quotation marks like this:

```
"INSERT into invoiceTbl(invoiceId, date, time) values (1, '21/6/2014', '11:13PM')"
```

Better practice is to use a single **datetime** (or named as **TimeStamp**) DB field containing both pieces of information (typically it corresponds to `DateTime.Now`). The modified query should look like:

```
"INSERT into invoiceTbl(invoiceId, datetime) values (1, '21/6/2014 11:13PM')"
```

Hope this will help. Rgds,

Comment: Alright, thank you alex! Your help and effort is much appreciated! :) Have a great day ahead~

Answer (score 0):

This error can also happen if you play with "connection" under server and you have (dataset).xsd file. In that case the connection string inside .xsd is disturbed and you get this error. In my case I had delete table in my xsd file and create the same table again with the new connection string and things worked fine.

This is approach is only good for small project. But at least it will you an idea, where the error is comming from.